# Setting "this" context on Monaco Editor for javascript

Tags: javascript, this, monaco-editor

When creating an editor for use with Javascript, is it possible to set the context that the "this" keyword will initially apply to (perhaps the global scope)?

Within the Monaco Editor Playground, if the value of the editor is initially blank and I type `this.` I would like to see the autocompletion list show the possibilities based on the appropriate context.

Even within a function, typing `this.` only results in words that appear in the function. There are no other options available.

Comment: Don't know if it's possible or not, but that would be a cool feature.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not out of the box. The problem is that **JavaScript is quite tricky language**. To be able to tell the current value of "**this**" - you need context. And most likely you will never have it.

To inspect code you have 3 levels of analysis:

1. **Syntax analysis**. Monaco has it. The syntax analysis can tell you basic things about the code. That var is a keyword, that "this" is identifier (if I remember correctly), that the line 2, pos 3 is an identifier, that is located in a function. Nothing more.
2. **Semantic analysis**. This type of analysis can also tell you the type of variables. It can give you more info on their type, their members, maybe their meaning for the code. This is not accurate in JS, because you can add or remove members to a type in JS at run time. So you can end up with totally different type. For example you may have a type that has 1 property. Then you can have a for loop in the code that adds as many properties as the iterations are (user1, user2, etc). So you end up with a Company.User1, Company.User2, etc, while you started with:

`var Company = {}`

So no 100% accurate analysis for that in JS.

4. **Runtime analysis** - this is more or less what browsers use to be able to tell what the type of a variable really is at the time of execution of the code (cause with JS you don't know). This is done at the time the code is executing.

With JS unless you get to the level 3 (Runtime analysis) - you are not guaranteed to be right. Most editors will use partially some sort of syntax analysis, some sort of semantic analysis and (maybe) just a bit of runtime analysis to try and make results more accurate. But they will never be accurate.

If you are sure what this. should be - you can provide your own autocompletion items in monaco editor, by attaching a completion provider:

https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.languages.completionitemprovider.html

Comment: Is there a way to return a object prototype instead of returning list of completions? In my case, I am generating the long list of completions at runtime using `registerCompletionItemProvider`.